# Is it possible to simulate Once Only login but 100 concurrent users with JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm testing a web application that only allow 5 active sessions. I want to simulate 100 concurrent REST API calls. But the below script doesn't work.
[Jmeter script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8Hyv.png)

Is it possible to simulate Once Only login but 100 concurrent users with JMeter?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by does  not work?  You cant achieve the load you want or you get unexpected errors?

Comment: @AlexKaramfilov If I set Number of Threads to 2 , Ramp-up period to 1, Each request will be run twice.

Comment: The easiest way probably is to use normal Thread group and just pass the Authorization header and set the threads to 100.  From what i understand you want to run 100 concurrent requests for single user. You already have HTTP header manager added so just need to pass the correct Authorization header and value. Example Authorization | Basic/Bearer token

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be understanding what does Once Only Controller do.

It runs its child(ren) during only first iteration of the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group), it doesn't execute them at the same time.

If you want to run 100 requests at the same moment - take a look at [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer)

If in your setup 5 requests are successful and other 95 are failing you could consider logging in somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) and then [pass the JMeter Variables holding the authentication context to the main Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-variables) so all 100 threads would share the same login details.